# Creating insert operation using hibernate and I am getting the following error?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

Creating insert operation using hibernate and I am getting the following error
Exception in thread

```
"main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.XMLContext.<init>(Lorg/hibernate/boot/spi/ClassLoaderAccess;)V
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.<init>(JPAMetadataProvider.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.generateDefaultReflectionManager(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:742)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:715)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:654)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:723)
    at com.pojoclass.main.InsertEmp.main(InsertEmp.java:20)
```

jar files list

```
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\antlr-2.7.7.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\cdi-api-1.1-PFD.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\classmate-1.3.0.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\dom4j-1.6.1.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\el-api-2.2.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\hibernate-annotations.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\hibernate-core-5.2.0.Final.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\jandex-2.0.0.Final.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\javax.inject-1.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Beta1.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\jsr250-api-1.0.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar
C:\Users\rbhupatiraju\Downloads\hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\hibernate-commons-annotations-3.0.0.ga.jar
```

Comment: Please, provide your `pom.xml` or the list of libraries.

Comment: // 'its just a basic application  which contains the mapping file and hibernate configuration file

Comment: pls verfiy all the entity class are properly configure in the xml. I suspect @entity annotation is missing in some entity class

Comment: i dint create any entity based class.just created pojo class

Comment: @KannanThangadurai It is a bootstrap problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are incorrect libraries in your classpath.

You don't need this libraries

```
hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\hibernate-annotations.jar 

hibernate-release-5.2.0.Final\lib\required\hibernate-commons-annotations-3.0.0.ga.jar
```

I advise you to use Maven or Gradle build.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity. im getting this exception

Comment: @BhRamya Looks like, you fix an error. Please, add your configuration, the code in which you create a session factory, the stack trace, and Hibernate version to your question.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need hibernate-annotation.jar because it is included in hibernate-core in hibernate 5
just remove hibernate annotation jar and keep only hibernate-commons-annotation.